# Web Services - When referencing a web service locally, it asks for credentials

Tags: .net, service, credentials

I am currently creating a web service locally. I created 2 separate files: One for the web app and the other for the web service. When I try to reference this web service from my web app, it asks for my credentials. It does not accept the credentials I inserted (which I know is correct). How do I remove this from my web service?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just had to modify the authentication in the web.config file of the web service. dugh